# Adding custom constraints to OMPL planners

Tags: ros, motion-planning, ompl, ompl-ros-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I'm currently trying to get an understanding of the [OMPL planners](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/index.html) and the [OMPL ROS interface](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ompl_ros_interface) and wondering how hard it would be to make the planners take into account custom constraints.

Custom constraints example A:

Apart from the individual joint position limits for each joint, the position difference between two (e.g. revolute) joints should not exceed a certain value.

Custom constraints example B:

Consider the growing of a tree. Would it be possible to make the added children of one node dependent of their parent? I.e. the joint configurations q_n+1 are dependent of the previous configuration q_n. In this way one could add variable joint limits.

I had a look at the OMPL code and got the feeling that the [State Sampler](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/availableSamplers.html) could be the right place to add such functionality. If that is true, does someone have an idea how to easily add this to the ompl_ros_interface?

Thanks for you hints!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38618/adding-custom-constraints-to-ompl-planners/) by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2062 on 2012-07-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Again very late reply -- Your intuition is correct. StateSampler is the way to go. However, that is not exposed in the ompl_ros_interface. However, in MoveIt (the replacement for arm_navigation) there is the option to supply your own state sampler. The API for that is a bit simpler right now, but the intention for it is to be essentially a wrapper for StateSampler, so you can implement functionality such as the one mention.

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2012-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1